# My implementation of the repository pattern

Tags: c#, repository

I'm using this pattern since a few months and I was wondering if I can make it any better.

The one thing I am not satisfied about is the dispose method. In every repository I have to add a dispose method that calls the base dispose method. Is there a way to get rid of the dispose method in every repository and just let it (automatically) call the base dispose method?

I'm using Linq2Sql.

**Interface:**

```
  public interface IRepository<TEntityType> where TEntityType : class
{
    TEntityType GetById(int id);

    IQueryable<TEntityType> GetAll();

    void Delete(TEntityType item);

    void Add(TEntityType item);
}
```

**Base:**

```
  public class BaseRepository<TEntityType> where TEntityType : class
{
    private readonly DataClassesDataContext _dataContext;

    protected BaseRepository()
    {
        _dataContext = new DataClassesDataContext();
    }

    protected Table<TEntityType> GetTable()
    {
        return _dataContext.GetTable<TEntityType>();
    }

    protected void SaveChanges()
    {
        _dataContext.SubmitChanges();
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose()
    {
        if (_dataContext != null)
        {
            _dataContext.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**Repository class:**

```
  public class FirstClassRepository : BaseRepository<FirstTable>, IRepository<FirstTable>, IDisposable
{
    public FirstTable GetById(int id)
    {
        return GetTable().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Test == id);
    }

    public IQueryable<FirstTable> GetAll()
    {
        return GetTable();
    }

    public void Delete(FirstTable item)
    {
        GetTable().DeleteOnSubmit(item);
    }

    public void Add(FirstTable item)
    {
        GetTable().InsertOnSubmit(item);
    }

    public new void Dispose()
    {
        base.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is DataClassesDataContext? are u using linq to sql?

Comment: @paritosh Yes i am. The topic said that already

Comment: Is `BaseRepository` always meant to be extended?

Comment: @mariosangiorgio its what you prefer.  I did saw some people using a base class and some skip this and tell somewhere else wat entity they want. I prefer this pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The one thing I am not satisfied about is the dispose method. In every repository I have to add a dispose method that calls the base dispose method.

**IDisposable**
The `IDisposable` interface should be impelemented in the `base` class. By using the default pattern of disposing, you will get this result

```
public class BaseRepository<TEntityType> : IDisposable where TEntityType : class
{
    private readonly DataClassesDataContext _dataContext;

    protected BaseRepository()
    {
        _dataContext = new DataClassesDataContext();
    }

    protected Table<TEntityType> GetTable()
    {
        return _dataContext.GetTable<TEntityType>();
    }

    protected void SaveChanges()
    {
        _dataContext.SubmitChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~BaseRepository()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    protected void Dispose(Boolean disposing)
    {
        // free unmanaged ressources here
        if (disposing)
        {
            // This method is called from Dispose() so it is safe to
            // free managed ressources here
            if (_dataContext != null)
            {
                _dataContext.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But wait, what if you also need to dispose ressources of the `FirstClassRepository` object which descends from that object. Then the `FirstClassRepository`object also needs to implement the `IDisposable` interface with the pattern below.

```
public class FirstClassRepository : BaseRepository<FirstTable>, IRepository<FirstTable>, IDisposable
{
    public FirstTable GetById(int id)
    {
        return GetTable().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Test == id);
    }

    public IQueryable<FirstTable> GetAll()
    {
        return GetTable();
    }

    public void Delete(FirstTable item)
    {
        GetTable().DeleteOnSubmit(item);
    }

    public void Add(FirstTable item)
    {
        GetTable().InsertOnSubmit(item);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        try
        {
            Dispose(true); //true: safe to free managed resources
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
        finally
        {
            base.Dispose();
        }
    }

    ~FirstClassRepository()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    protected void Dispose(Boolean disposing)
    {
        // free unmanaged ressources here
        if (disposing)
        {
            // This method is called from Dispose() so it is safe to
            // free managed ressources here
        }
    }
}
```

If the `FirstClassRepository` obect doesn't need to dispose ressources you can omit the implementation of `IDisposable`.

EDIT based on comment:

The `~FirstClassRepository()` method is what the compiler takes as beeing the `Finalize()` method of the object. If you forget to call the `Dispose()` method of that object, this method will be called at the time your object is destructed.
So as the method is implemented by calling the overloaded `Dispose(Boolean)` method with the `parameter == false`, only unmanaged ressources will be freed (where the comment is written) as the GC takes care of the managed objects.

Otherwise your implementation looks fine for me.

Some SO links
[proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/538238/2655508)
[when-should-i-use-gc-suppressfinalize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/151244/2655508)

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer, i do have one question. What does: ~BaseRepository()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    } do?